# How do I do this action on enter press or submit?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#.login.button').click(function() {
```

and

```
 $('#.register.button').click(function() {
```

Both of these do things, how would I run the script under them on click OR enter press?

Here's my .js jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#.login.button').click(function() {

        // Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

        $(loginBox).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
    });
    $("#.sign-in.button").click(function() {
    var empty = $(this).parent().find("input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length) {
        var notification = noty({text: "Error: Some fields were not filled out" , type:"error",  timeout: 2500, layout:"topCenter"});
        return false;
    }
 var username = $('#username').val(),
 password = $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "components/login.php",
    data:{username:username, password:password},
    type: "post",
    success: function(data) {
                    if(data == 'success') {
                        var notification = noty({text: "Welcome, "+username+"!" , type:"success",  timeout: 2500, layout:"topCenter"});
                        setTimeout(function(){
                         window.location = document.URL;
                    }, 3000);}
                    else {
                    var notification = noty({text: "Error: Incorrect Username/Password" , type:"error",  timeout: 2500, layout:"topCenter"});
                    }
    },
    error: function(html) {
    alert('error');
},
    statusCode: {
     404: function() {
       //404 here
     }
    }

});
return false;
});

$('#.register.button').click(function() {
                var registerBox = $(this).attr('href');
                $(registerBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border
        var popMargTop = ($(registerBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
        var popMargLeft = ($(registerBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

        $(registerBox).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
            return false;
    });

$("#.log-out.button").click(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "components/logout.php",
    success: function(data) {
                        var notification = noty({text: "Successfully logged out!" , type:"success",  timeout: 2500, layout:"topCenter"});
                        setTimeout(function(){
                         window.location = document.URL;
                    }, 3000);
    },
    error: function(html) {
    alert('error');
},
    statusCode: {
     404: function() {
       //404 here
     }
    }

});
return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#password").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#loginbtn').click();
    };
});
```

Then make your button:

```
<button id="loginbtn" type="button">Sign in</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

First things first, `$('#.login.button')` won't work.

```
$('#loginbutton')
```

and

```
<button id="loginbutton">Log in</button>
```

will.

That done, you should always bind the event to the form submission simply because there's more than one way to submit a form.

```
$('#theform').on('submit', function(){
    // do something useful here
});
```

Assuming it's in the form the button submit it. You can make it do stuff before, let's say you had a register and login button that use the same email and password fields.

```
$('#loginbutton').on('click', function(){
    // do the unique thing here
    // then let the form submit
    return true;
});
```

or if it's for some reason this button is not in the form

```
$('#loginbutton').on('click', function(){
    // do the unique thing here
    // then let the form submit
    $('#theform').trigger('submit');
});
```

I think this is what you are asking.

Comment: I'd also say a few words about the selectors that look like `$("#.sign-in.button")`

Comment: Is there a way to write `('or #.login.button').click or ('#theform').on('submit', function(){` ?

Comment: @Blender I noticed `$('#.login.button')` but it's probably valid for this: `<button id="" class="login button">`

Comment: @user1973551, yes bind the form, trigger the event with the button. see my edit.

Comment: @Blender in that case, what a stupid idea! lol. edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Because your HTML does not have a #loginbtn which is what your JS is targetting. Nor does your form have the id formlogin. #RTFM

Comment: Oops, forgot to ftp that over. Okay, now the btn submits, but enter doesn't.